# unify column month (SQL query)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a SQL query that takes the sum of a float field in a given month. But I am not able to unify these months when I map the month field to the main query and with that my result is doubling.

The result I need is:

month | client_id | value_one | value_two | value_three | value_four

Bellow is my query

```
SELECT
    client.client_id,
    value_one.value_one,
    value_one.month_one
    value_two.value_two,
    value_two.month_two,
    value_three.value_three,
    value_three.month_three,
    value_four.value_four,
    value_four.month_four

FROM
    client,
    (SELECT to_char(to_timestamp(t1.date_timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.ff3"Z"'), 'mm') as month_one,
            client_id,
            sum(value) as value_one
       FROM value_one,
            dim_time t1
      WHERE value_one.dt_timestamp_id = t1.time_id
   GROUP BY to_char(to_timestamp(t1.date_timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.ff3"Z"'), 'mm'), client_id
    ) value_one,
    (SELECT to_char(to_timestamp(t2.date_timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.ff3"Z"'), 'mm') as month_two,
            client_id,
            sum(value) as value_two
       FROM value_two,
            dim_time t2
      WHERE value_two.dt_timestamp_id = t2.time_id
   GROUP BY to_char(to_timestamp(t2.date_timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.ff3"Z"'), 'mm'), client_id
    ) value_two,
    (SELECT to_char(to_timestamp(t3.date_timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.ff3"Z"'), 'mm') as month_three,
            client_id,
            sum(value) as value_three
       FROM value_three,
            dim_time t3
      WHERE value_three.dt_timestamp_id = t3.time_id
   GROUP BY to_char(to_timestamp(t3.date_timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.ff3"Z"'), 'mm'), client_id
    ) value_three,
    (SELECT to_char(to_timestamp(t4.date_timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.ff3"Z"'), 'mm') as month_four,
            client_id,
            sum(value) as value_four
       FROM value_four,
            dim_time t4
      WHERE value_three.dt_timestamp_id = t4.time_id
   GROUP BY to_char(to_timestamp(t4.date_timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.ff3"Z"'), 'mm'), client_id
    ) value_four
WHERE client.client_id = value_one.client_id(+)
  AND client.client_id = value_two.client_id(+)
  AND client.client_id = value_three.client_id(+)
  AND client.client_id = value_four.client_id(+)
```

Does anyone knows how to solve it?

Comment: Please provide the sample input and expected output with data.

Comment: Does Month_one, Two, Three and Four contains same values for each row ?

Comment: @SureshGajera yes, exactly the same value (same month). That name is an alias, but as you can see is the same search table (dim_time)

Comment: If All 4 column has same values per row then can we use any one column as month and do group by Month, Client_id ? 
or let me know if I am missing anything.

If possible, please share the sample data.